# Pandas pd.pivot_table gives a KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

I have a `df` dataframe with 4 columns `'year'`, `'cath1'`, `'cath2'` and `'cath3'`
and 2000 entries corresponding to products, with corresponding year of production, and a value in each 3 categories.

I would like to create another dataframe with the same 3 category columns and compute the average value of all products for each specific year in each of these categories.

I tried with the following code but it does not work.

```
df1=pd.pivot_table(df,index=['year'],values=['0','1','2'],aggfunc=np.mean)
```

```
Exception has occurred: KeyError '0'
```

Comment: Please share the dataframe

Comment: KeyError '0' means that you don't have either a row index with a label of '0' nor column header with a label of '0'.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct but you need to use the column name in the values.

```
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['year'], values=['cath1', 'cath2','cath3'],
                          aggfunc=np.mean)
```

Comment: my list(df) actually is : ['year', 0, 1, 2]

Comment: it's better to have proper names for your columns. try this before pivoting df.columns = ['Datec', 'year', 'cath1', 'cath2', 'cath3']

Comment: also to @yatu point, it's always good to share a few rows of your data when asking a question so people can replicate your result.

Comment: You are right I changed my headers and everything works now. thank you.